# Idiomatic way to use bootstrap to layout a grid pattern of variable items

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am learning to use a utility first css approach to create a grid pattern layout for a variable number of search results.  The appearance I want to achieve is described by this image here:

[image]

This was my solution using bootstrap css framework.

```js
function loadMore() {
   fetch('search-results.php?current='+document.querySelectorAll('.item').length)
   .then(response=>response.text())
   .then(result=>document.querySelector('.results').innerHTML += result);
}
```

```css
body,div {padding:0;margin:0;}

.item {
  display:block;
  background:#333;
  color:white;
  border:2px solid white;
}

.item.col-12 {
  height:75vh;
}
.item.col-6 {
  height:50vh;
}
.item.col-4 {
  height:30vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="results"></div>
<button type="button" onClick="loadMore()">Load More</button>
```

// PHP FILE - search-results.php

```
<?php
//$n = rand(1,10);
$n = $_REQUEST['current'] < 1 ? 1 : 8;
for($c=0;$c<$n;$c++)
{
  $current = $c+intval($_REQUEST['current']);
  if(
    $current === 0 ||
    ($current-1)%8 === 0 ||
    ($current-3)%8 === 0 ||
    ($current+2)%8 === 0
  )
    echo '<div class="row">';

  if($current === 0)
    echo '<div class="item col-12">'.$current.'</div>';
  else if(($current-1)%8 === 0 || ($current-2)%8 === 0)
    echo '<div class="item col-6">'.$current.'</div>';
  else
    echo '<div class="item col-4">'.$current.'</div>';


  if(
    $current === 0 ||
    ($current-2)%8 === 0 ||
    ($current-2)%8 === 0 ||
    ($current-5)%8 === 0
  )
    echo '</div>';
}
```

My bootstrap approach has several problems that I do not know how to resolve:

1. When `search-results.php` returns a random number of items, the opening and closing `<div class="row">` tags are not inserted at the right times after multiple "Load More" button clicks.
2. I don't like the arithmatic that I have to perform to properly place the open and closee `<div class="row">` tags and to decide whether to write a `col-12 || col-6 || col-4`.  This all seems unnecessarily complex.

**QUESTION : What is the idiomatic way to use bootstrap (or any other utility-first css approach) to write a pattern grid layout that receives random number of results?**

### **EXTRA - PLAIN APPROACH**

My problem above can be solved using a plain CSS approach as shown with this code here:

// CSS FILE

```
body,div {padding:0;margin:0;}
.results {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.item {
  display:block;
  background:#333;
  color:white;

  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:10px;
  width:33.333%;
  height:30vh;
  border:2px solid white;
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
  width:100%;
  height:75vh;
}
.item:nth-child(8n+2),
.item:nth-child(8n+3) {
  width: 50%;
  height:50vh;
}
```

// PHP FILE

```
<?php
$n = rand(1,10);
for($c=0;$c<$n;$c++)
  echo '<div class="item">'.($c+intval($_REQUEST['current'])).'</div>';
```

The PHP code is much simpler and I do not have to deal with wrapping `<div>` elements.

Comment: Bootstraps requires class for a static layout, this is not what you need. For a repeating pattern.  :nth-child(xn) is indeed what you need if it is to be manage from a style sheet.

Comment: is there any other utility first css framework that would be suitable?  There are teams I'm working with that make utility first css the mandatory development style.

Comment: Have you looked at [row columns classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#row-columns)? You can specify how many columns should be in a row without having to keep adding rows manually.

Comment: if you want to use boostrap anyway, then you need to set the class from your pHp script and use the `flex-wrap` class on a single `.row` container. possible rendering : https://jsfiddle.net/z0crhesy/ If this is what you need , you can remove your tags and only keep the php tag if you can't fix your script to distribute the right class. ;)